# Does "trusted device" unlocking work with an encrypted device?

Tags: lock-screens, encryption

Since Android 5.0, encrypting a device [doesn't require](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2014/10/revisiting-android-disk-encryption.html) configuring a complex alphanumeric screen lock password anymore.

Does this also work combined with with [unlocking the device using a "trusted device"](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements/enhancements50.html) connected over bluetooth, or a trusted NFC tag, a.k.a. "Smart Lock"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. I'm on a Nexus 6, fully encrypted, and I use multiple Smart Lock features, including Trusted devices, Trusted places, Trusted face, and On-Body detection.